# Solidity array overflow

Tags: solidity, arrays, overflow

I'm trying to understand this array overflow attack on Solidity.
(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gUqHgFuSsqg)

In that video, the code is basically like this

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17; 

contract ArrayOverflow{
    uint256 public target = 10;
    uint256[] public array = [9,8];

    function modifyArray (uint256 _index, uint256 _value){
        array[_index] = _value;
    }

    function popLength() public{
        // cause overflow
        array.length--;
    }

    function getLength() constant returns(uint256){
        return array.length;
    }

}
```

What he did is call `popLength()` three times to make the array overflowed.

After the above step, we can see the storage loaded is like this

[image]

So the `0xfffffff...fff` is the length value.

Then we convert the hexadecimal value to address.

```
   web3.sha3('0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001', {encoding: 'hex'})
// => 0xb10e2d527612073b26eecdfd717e6a320cf44b4afac2b0732d9fcbe2b7fa0cf6
```

The following part is what I felt confused.

He exeuted the following command to find the address of `target`

```
perl -Mbigint -E 'say ((2**256 - 0xb10e2d527612073b26eecdfd717e6a320cf44b4afac2b0732d9fcbe2b7fa0cf6 + 0)->as_hex)'
```

The output magically becomes the address of `target`, how does that happen?

Comment: I think you mean the address of `target`.

Comment: Sorry, that's my fault. I 've edited it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you mean the address of `target`, not the address of `X` (which is a smart contract). In the video you linked to, that variable is called `x` (lowercase).

https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/03/09/understanding-ethereum-smart-contract-storage/ may help you understand the layout of storage.

`array` is the second state variable in the contract, so it's located at slot `1`. For a dynamic array, that means the length is stored at slot `1`, and the actual array data starts at `keccak256(uint256(1))`. You've computed that as `0xb10e2d527612073b26eecdfd717e6a320cf44b4afac2b0732d9fcbe2b7fa0cf6`. The second element of the array will be at `0xb10e2d527612073b26eecdfd717e6a320cf44b4afac2b0732d9fcbe2b7fa0cf7`, etc. (adding 1 each time).

Now the trick is to figure out what element of the array occupies the same storage as `target`. Because `target` is the first state variable in the contract, it's located at slot `0`. Due to integer overflow, we can also find this at 2**256. So we take `2**256 - 0xb10e2d527612073b26eecdfd717e6a320cf44b4afac2b0732d9fcbe2b7fa0cf6`, and that gives us our offset (array index).

Comment: Thanks for your effort, that's a good explanation!